# react native conditionally fetch data too much re-rendering issue

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I want to achieve such scenario in my application:

- when the user taps on a Company for checking its details I want to show all products of the company first.
- when the user taps on a Category in the Details page I want to show only products related to that category.

for both cases I need to call API with specific arguments so here's my code:

**Card Details Page:**

```js
const CardDetails = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const companyId = props.route.params.id;
  const companyName = props.route.params.companyName;
  const companyImage = props.route.params.companyImage;
  const companyLocation = props.route.params.companyLocation;

  const [isCatLoading, setIsCatLoading] = useState(true);
  const [isProductLoading, setIsProductLoading] = useState(true);
  const [CompanyCategories, setCompanyCategories] = useState([]);
  
  let products = [];
  console.log(products)

  const fetchCategories = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`myURL`);
    const data = await response.json();
    setCompanyCategories(data)
    setIsCatLoading(false)
  };

  const fetchProducts = () => {
    dispatch(SelectedProductsByCat.fetchSelectedCatProducts(companyId, [7, 8, 10, 11]))
      .then(
        setIsProductLoading(false)
      )

  }

  if (setIsProductLoading) {
    products = useSelector(state => state.products.availableSelectedCatProducts)
  }


  useEffect(() => {
    fetchCategories()
  }, [products])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchProducts()
  }, [products])


  return (
    <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false} style={styles.screen}>
      <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.titleText}>{companyName}</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
        <View style={styles.mainImageContainer}>
          <Image style={styles.mainImage} source={{ uri: companyImage }} />
        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.optionsContainer}>
        <Option title={companyLocation} />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.typeSelectionContainer}>
        {
          isCatLoading ?
            <DotIndicator color='#253D59' size={20} count={5} />
            :
            <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.horizontalScrollContainer} horizontal={true} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
              <CategorySelection
                companyId={companyId}
                options={CompanyCategories.map((el, i) => {
                  return { id: el.id, name: el.title, icon: el.icon, selected: false }
                })}
              />
            </ScrollView>
        }
      </View>
      {
        isProductLoading ?
          <View>
            <DotIndicator color='#253D59' size={20} count={5} />
          </View>
          :
          <View style={styles.resultsContainer}>
            {
              products != 'undefined' && products.length > 0 ?
                products.map((el, index) => {
                  return (
                    <TouchableOpacity
                      key={el.id.toString()}
                      style={styles.resultImageContainer}
                      onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('OfficeDetails', {
                        productId: el.id.toString(),
                        productName: el.productName,
                        productPrice: el.productPrice,
                        productImages: el.groupOfImage
                      })}
                    >
                      <Image style={styles.mainImage} source={{ uri: el.groupOfImage[0].imageAddress }} />
                      <View style={styles.seatsContainer}>
                        <Text style={styles.seatsText}>{el.productPrice} <Text style={styles.price}>&#8378;</Text></Text>
                      </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  )
                })
                :
                <View style={{ marginTop: 40 }}>
                  <NoData size={wp(40)} />
                </View>
            }
          </View>
      }
    </ScrollView>
  )
}
```

**and this is the Categories Component:**

```
const CategorySelection = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const companyId = props.companyId
  const [options, setOptions] = useState(props.options.map((el, index) => {
    return {
      id: el.id,
      name: el.name,
      selected: el.selected
    }
  }))

  const selectedCategoriesId = options.filter(el => el.selected).map(el => el.id);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchProductsHandler();
  }, [options])

  const fetchProductsHandler = () => {
    if(selectedCategoriesId.length == 0) {
      dispatch(SelectedProductsByCat.fetchSelectedCatProducts(companyId, options.map((el, index) => el.id)));
    } 
  }
  
  const onRadioBtnClick = (item) => {
    let updatedState = options.map((el) =>{
      
      if(el.id == item.id) {
        return { ...el, selected: !el.selected }
      } else {
        return { ...el, selected: el.selected }
      }
    } 
    );
    setOptions(updatedState)
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
      {
        options.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => {
                onRadioBtnClick(item)
              }
              }
              key={item.id}
              selected={item.selected}
              style={[styles.buttonContainer, props.buttonStyle]}>
              <View style={[styles.button,
              item.selected == true ? styles.selectedButton : null
              ]}>
                <Text style={[styles.buttonText,
                item.selected == true ? styles.selectedButtonText : null,
                {fontSize : item.name.split(' ')[0].length > 10 ? hp(1.5) : hp(2.1)}
                ]}>{item.name}</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )
        })
      }
    </View>
  )
}
```

and here's the screenshot of the page:

[image]

again what I need to achieve here is to show all products at first, but when the user tap on categories I need to show related products, and also when the user deselects categories all products show again.
if you need more code for the project just let me know in the comments. any help would be appreciated <3